# New conditions to ensure martingality of stochastic exponential?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I am currently doing a project with focus on the Girsanov theorem, and I want to include some of the conditions which would ensure that the stochastic exponential $\mathcal{E}(L)=\exp(L-\langle L\rangle/2)$, where $L$ is a nonnegative, continuous local martingale, is in fact a true martingale. Rather than just turning to Karatzas & Shreve or something similar, I found an article by Johannes Ruf (http://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.5583.pdf). The theorem he proves can be stated as follows:

First, let $\mathcal{T}$ denote the set of all stopping times $τ$ for which there exists some $n_τ \in\mathbb{N}$ with $τ ≤ (T − 1/n_τ)∧n_τ$.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\times[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ denote a continuous function, such that

$\displaystyle\limsup_{t\to\infty}f(B_t+t,t)\cdot\exp\left(-B_t-\frac{t}{2}\right)=\infty,$

for some Brownian motion $B$. If

$\displaystyle\sup_{\tau\in\mathcal{T}}\left\{E\left[ f(L_{\tau},\langle L\rangle_{\tau})\textbf{1}_{\{ \mathcal{E}(L)_{\tau}>0\}}\right]\right\}<\infty$,

then $\mathcal{E}(L)$ is a (uniformly integrable) martingale on $[0,T]$

It seems rather nice to me that this theorem (applied to $f(x,y)=\exp(y/2)$ and $f(x,y)=\exp(x/2)$, respectively) immediately implies the criteria of both Novikov and Kazamaki. Ruf also goes on to slightly generalize these conditions (for example by showing martingality of $\mathcal{E}(aL)$).

So, for quite some time I've been sitting to myself thinking "pfft, how hard can it be. Surely, I can apply the theorem to an appropriate function and come to a nice conclusion". The problem is that I can't, which is why I've come here. My approach until now has been all trial and error, but this isn't exactly working out for me. Does anyone have an idea for a smarter way of using this theorem to obtain some nice conditions? I don't necessarily need a specific method, I would just to hear if someone has a good idea. I feel like the more I look at it, the less I see.

Comment: @ user73048 : The is more suitable to the MO forum in my opinion as it is research level question. best regards

Comment: @ user73048 : More generally what is it that you want ? Characterizing all functions $f$ (or a particular family of such functions) so that you can apply those $f$ to a general candidate $L$ ? Do you want to have a mechanical way of calculating $sup_{\tau\in\mathcal{T}}\left\{E\left[ f(L_{\tau},\langle L\rangle_{\tau})\textbf{1}_{\{ \mathcal{E}(L)_{\tau}>0\}}\right]\right\}$ to check the criteria more easily ? Best regards

Comment: In fact, any of those ideas would be quite nice. Mostly, however, I've tried with various functions satisfying the limsup-condition. It is rather tedious work, but having a general way of easily calculating the supremum sure would help.